# Convert SQL query to C# (SQL query converts base36 code to DateTime)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, base36

I'd like to be able to encode \ decode id's containing the datetime in a 7 digit \ base36 configuration, but despite having a SQL query that decodes Id's, so far have had no luck.

I have a SQL query that is able to convert the code to a date time.

Using the following ids, I'm hoping to get the corresponding datetimes.

```
    id          Date Time
    ------------------------------------
    A7LXZMM     2004-02-02 09:34:47.000
    KWZKXEX     2018-11-09 11:15:46.000
    LIZTMR9     2019-09-13 11:49:46.000
```

Query:

```
DECLARE @xdate DATETIME, @offset INT
DECLARE @recid VARCHAR(20)

SET @recid = 'KWZKXEX'
SET @offset = (SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())) /************* Number of hours offset from GMT ************/

SELECT 
    DATEADD(ss, @offset +
                (POWER(CAST(36 AS BIGINT), 6) *
                 CASE
                    WHEN (SELECT ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@recid, 1, 1))) = 0
                       THEN (SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(@recid, 1, 1))) - 55
                       ELSE (SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(@recid, 1, 1))) - 48
                 END +
                 POWER(CAST(36 AS BIGINT), 5) *
    case
    when(select isnumeric(substring(@recid,2,1))) = 0
    then(select ascii(substring(@recid,2,1))) - 55
    else (select ascii(substring(@recid,2,1))) - 48
    End
    +
    POWER(cast(36 as bigint),4) *
    case
    when(select isnumeric(substring(@recid,3,1))) = 0
    then(select ascii(substring(@recid,3,1))) - 55
    else (select ascii(substring(@recid,3,1))) - 48
    End
    +
    POWER(cast(36 as bigint),3) *
    case
    when(select isnumeric(substring(@recid,4,1))) = 0
    then(select ascii(substring(@recid,4,1))) - 55
    else (select ascii(substring(@recid,4,1))) - 48
    End
    +
    POWER(cast(36 as bigint),2) *
    case
    when(select isnumeric(substring(@recid,5,1))) = 0
    then(select ascii(substring(@recid,5,1))) - 55
    else (select ascii(substring(@recid,5,1))) - 48
    End
    +
    POWER(cast(36 as bigint),1) *
    case
    when(select isnumeric(substring(@recid,6,1))) = 0
    then(select ascii(substring(@recid,6,1))) - 55
    else (select ascii(substring(@recid,6,1))) - 48
    End
    +
    POWER(cast(36 as bigint),0) *
    case
    when(select isnumeric(substring(@recid,7,1))) = 0
    then(select ascii(substring(@recid,7,1))) - 55
    else (select ascii(substring(@recid,7,1))) - 48
    End
    )
    /50
    ,'1/1/1990')
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;         
using System.Text;
using System.Numerics;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string sRecid = "A7LXZMM";
        char c0 = sRecid[0];
        char c1 = sRecid[1];
        char c2 = sRecid[2];
        char c3 = sRecid[3];
        char c4 = sRecid[4];
        char c5 = sRecid[5];
        char c6 = sRecid[6];

        double d6, d5, d4, d3, d2, d1, d0, dsecs;

        Console.WriteLine("c0 = " + c0.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();

        d6 = Math.Pow(36, 6) * ((Char.IsNumber(c0)) ? (byte)c0 - 55 : (byte)c0 - 48);
        d5 = Math.Pow(36, 5) * ((Char.IsNumber(c1)) ? (byte)c1 - 55 : (byte)c1 - 48);
        d4 = Math.Pow(36, 4) * ((Char.IsNumber(c2)) ? (byte)c2 - 55 : (byte)c2 - 48);
        d3 = Math.Pow(36, 3) * ((Char.IsNumber(c3)) ? (byte)c3 - 55 : (byte)c3 - 48);
        d2 = Math.Pow(36, 2) * ((Char.IsNumber(c4)) ? (byte)c4 - 55 : (byte)c4 - 48);
        d1 = Math.Pow(36, 1) * ((Char.IsNumber(c5)) ? (byte)c5 - 55 : (byte)c5 - 48);
        d0 = Math.Pow(36, 0) * ((Char.IsNumber(c6)) ? (byte)c6 - 55 : (byte)c6 - 48);


        dsecs = d6 + d5 + d4 +  d3 +  d2 +  d1 +  d0 / 50;

        DateTime dt = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
        dt =  dt.AddSeconds( dsecs ).ToLocalTime();

    Console.WriteLine("d6 = " + d6.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("d5 = " + d5.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("d4 = " + d4.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("d3 = " + d3.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("d2 = " + d2.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("d1 = " + d1.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("d0 = " + d0.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("dsecs = " + dsecs.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("dt = " + dt.ToString());
    }
}
```

When I use the following Ids in SQL, I get the following dates.

```
    id          Date Time
    ------------------------------------
    A7LXZMM     2004-02-02 09:34:47.000
    KWZKXEX     2018-11-09 11:15:46.000
    LIZTMR9     2019-09-13 11:49:46.000
```

Unfortunately my C# "conversion" is wildly inaccurate.

Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This is definitely in the top 5 of complicated ways to safe a couple of bytes. At least, I assume that's the reason for storing a date so mindbogglingly.

Comment: Nope, its not to save bytes. I'm working with a db that is 20+ years old and need the id to correspond with old data while still being url friendly. The full id is longer, I just had problems solving the date part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the `Char.IsNumber`... checks flipped in your C# code compared to your SQL script.

In your SQL, you're subtracting `55` if the character **is not** a number, and `48` otherwise.

In your C# code you're subtracting `55` if the character **is** a number, and `48` otherwise.

You're also not calculating `dsecs` correctly I don't think. You need to add `d6` through `d0` then divide by `50`. The way you have it now, you'll divide `d0` by `50` then add all the other `dn` variables.

In other words...

`dsecs = d6 + d5 + d4 +  d3 +  d2 +  d1 +  d0 / 50;`

Should be

`dsecs = (d6 + d5 + d4 +  d3 +  d2 +  d1 +  d0) / 50;`

Comment: Joshua, thank you very much for that. You're right.
I now just need to add the offset and it works.